# Find out how git removed a file that should be ignored

Tags: git, gitignore

I currently have a git repo set up as a bare repository that then `git checkout -f`s to a public folder for publishing. Recently a commit was made that seemed to delete a file that is in .gitignore.

Is there a way to see how that file was deleted? Pulling down these changes to my local deleted the file on my machine too:

```
nic@TALRASHA:/mnt/code/repository$ git pull
remote: Counting objects: 42, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (20/20), done.
remote: Total 26 (delta 18), reused 9 (delta 6)
Unpacking objects: 100% (26/26), done.
From ssh://[server-address]/var/www/vhosts/thewebsite/repository
   f470eff..82dc3bf  live       -> server/live
Updating f470eff..82dc3bf
Fast-forward
 application/views/templates/owners/default.php |  20 +++++++++++---------
 layout/owners/images/sprites-mobile-pages.png  | Bin 0 -> 89606 bytes
 layout/owners/js/owners.js                     |  44 ++++++
 src/less/layout/owners/dashboard.less          |  25 +++++++++++++++----
 4 files changed, 76 insertions(+), 13 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 layout/owners/images/sprites-mobile-pages.png
```

Running `git log --follow -- filename` returns blank result.
Running `git ls-files filename --error-unmatch` returns "error: pathspec 'filename' did not match any file(s) known to git."

Comment: That's not what `gitignore` is for.

Files can be added to your repo if they're in `.gitignore`. Files can be removed from your repo if they're in `.gitignore`. All `.gitignore` does is prevent Git from listing them when you use `git status` or automatically adding them when you add parent directories.

Comment: So how do I find out if git changed this file? I know you can track a file explicitly if it is in .gitignore but these branches shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: Edit: Checked wrong file. The file I am after is not tracked by git according to `git ls-files filename --error-unmatch`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `git checkout` can delete one of your ignored, untracked files. That could happen if someone else tracked the file in a different branch.

## Forensics

One way to **determine whether someone tracked a file they shouldn't have tracked** is to run `git log` with a limit by file name.

```
git log --follow -- filename.ext
```

If you don't need to track renames, you can use a simplified search.

```
git log -- filename.txt
```

Both will display commits that impacted the filename.ext file. The first one (with `--follow`) will also detect renames. When searching by path, the `--` is necessary before the filename.ext, to inform git that it's a file name.

## Scenario / Example

Here is a scenario in PowerShell with git in which someone may have added an ignored file.

### Create and initialize local git repo

```
new-item -type directory "repo"
cd repo
git init
```

### Add a gitignore and a test.txt file to ignore

```
new-item -type file ".gitignore"
add-content .gitignore "*.txt" 
new-item -type file "test.txt"
git add -A;
git commit -m "Add gitignore";
```

At this point, git is NOT tracking test.txt, because it is ignored.

### Force add the test.txt file

```
git add -f test.txt
git commit -n "Force add test.txt"
```

Git is now tracking test.txt, and a checkout of HEAD~1 will erase it, even though it is in your .gitignore.

### Checkout your previous commit to delete the ignored test.txt

```
git checkout HEAD~1
# this will delete the "ignored" file.
```

Similarly, if another person (force) added the test.txt file, a checkout of their branch may have deleted your ignored, untracked file.

Comment: How would I find out if this is the case?

Comment: One thing you could try is to examine the log. The log would contain evidence of someone adding and committing the file in question.

Comment: Is there no command to check or do I have to manually go back through hundreds or more commits looking for changes?

Comment: Nothing comes up using `git log --follow`. Is that because the file doesn't exist anymore?

Comment: If you run `git log --follow -- filename.txt` and nothing displays, then that means git has never tracked the file.

Comment: So that means file tracking is not the cause of the issue? What other options is there?

Comment: Did you make sure that you were at the tip of your current branch before running `git log`; that's important because the log command starts from your HEAD, and the person may have tracked it in a later commit.

Comment: I ran both from the branch head and the commit before I pulled in the change that removed it. No dice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70747/discussion-between-shaun-luttin-and-beaverusiv).

Answer (score 1):

I found out the reason: git was used to track the file in a branch that was merge commited, leaving no trace in the main branch's log. Looking into the log of the merged branch showed the operations on the file.